# GPS and NETWORK_PROVIDER not working on real device

Tags: android, location

I have tried to get current location using NETWORK_PROVIDER and register

```
LocationListener:
locManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 10000, 0, locListener);
```

I have added following permissions in AndroidManifest.xml:

```
android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION
android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION
android.permission.INTERNET
```

But `onLocationChanged(Location location)` never called.

And if I tried to get location with:

```
locManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
```

then it always return null location.

I don't know where I am wrong.
Any help should appreciate me.

Comment: Do you have GPS enabled in your phone?

Comment: Yes GPS enabled in my device.

Comment: onLocationChanged(Location location) will called, when the Latitude and longitude values will be changed. So, better to check the application on the real device and change the place from one position to another position(move long distances for better results).

Comment: I have tried Lenovo Ideatab, and changed place from one position to another but onLocationChanged(Location lcoation) method not invoked if I tried to get location using getLastKnownLocation() returning null location.

Comment: I am following the Android Location Provider tutorial:
http://www.android10.org/index.php/articleslocationmaps/226-android-location-providers-gps-network-passive

Answer (score 0):

Have you executed the Method `requestLocationUpdates` on your LocationManager instance?

Comment: Yes I have executed the requestLocationUpdates method in following way locManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 10000, 0, locListener);

Answer (score 0):

Two likely causes:
1) GPS is not enabled on the device
2) you're not giving it enough time to get a position fix (my device can take up to 30s to get a fix).  Until it gets a fix, the location manager will return null.  Likewise, until it gets a fix, and then the device moves and the device gets a second fix, it won't trigger the 'onLocationChanged' event

Comment: GPS is enabled on my device. I have tried to set 60s to get a position but onLocationChanged() not invoked. GPS not a issue, because I am tried to get location from NETWORK_PROVIDER.

Comment: If you use Google Maps (for example), is that able to retrieve a GPS (or network) location fix within a reasonable time?  This would at least confirm that your GPS is working, and give you an idea of how quick your device can get a fix under local conditions